# PHP Login Counter

Tags: php, variables, authentication, counter

Im having a problem for retaining variables. I guess when you submit a form the variables will be reset to default. so I dont know how to make a limit of 3 login attempts only before it says "Go Away! Hacker!". With just using php and nothing else.
Anyone has a clue? Don't worry for Security because this is just an example of exercise my prof gave us and we need to do it with just php alone. so dont worries about hackers resetting cookies.

NOTE: I'm only using XAMPP to make php work in localhost.

Here's the Code in PHP:

```
<center><form action="" method="post"><br>
User ID: <input type="text" name="id"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="login">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $counter = 0;
    $counter++;
    $vid = 'hanzo';
    $vpass = '123456';
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $c = "<center>";
    if(empty($id)) echo "$c Please Input Username.<br>";
    else if(empty($pass)) echo "$c Please Input Password.<br>";
    else if($vid==$id && $vpass==$pass) echo "$c Login Succesfully<br>";    
    else if($counter>3) echo "$c Go Away! Hacker!<br>";
    else echo "$c Invalid Username/Password<br> Login Attempt: $counter";
}
?>
```

Comment: I suggest recording failed attempts in the database, and when they reach 3, for the last 5 minutes, fail a login even if correct and dont give a reason for the failure. this should help prevent brute force attacks

Comment: You'll need to store the counter in permanent storage, like your database. Then reset it to zero when a successful login occurs, or when enough time has passed.

Comment: @Hanzo Kimura If you are going to use one of the session options, make sure you only check for posted forms, otherwise a simple page-load will increase your counter already.

Answer (score 4):

You can stick variables in the session to keep them for a user/client-machine through more than one page load. https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Each time your script runs, it starts with a blank slate. All variables are undefined except for the magic $_X variables. You need to put any of your own data somewhere that will persist through multiple runs - the session, a cookie, a database, a text file, etc.

Sessions are probably the easiest way to do it. Since they have a client-side element though, they are not completely secure. A relatively sophisticated user could circumvent a session check.

Comment: I don't think blocking cookies requires a very sophisticated user :)

Comment: @Martin Anyway, hacker will probably use some sort of automatization and won't block cookies in a browser

Comment: @galymzhan you're right about the automation but it'll likely be a primitive script so cookies will probably be disabled by default

Comment: Hey Thanks for this useful information ^_^ I'll try this one :)

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
<input type='hidden' />
```

won't really do much to prevent a determined hacker but you can use it to store variables between pages without enabling sessions if you have a particular aversion to them.

otherwise

```
session_start();  
if (isset($_SESSION['loginCount']))
{
   $_SESSION['loginCount']++;
   if ($_SESSION['loginCount'] > 3)
   {
     echo 'Bog Off!';
     exit;
   }
} else {
   $_SESSION['loginCount'] = 1;
}
```

This would be better BUT be advised that if your would be hacker clears their browser cache the session will be reset. Best bet would be to track the source IP address in a database but even that can be worked around with proxies.

Comment: What will i do with the hidden input? anyway i'll try the session one

Comment: with the hidden input, you can set the value element to a variable of the same name eg `<input type='hidden' name='myvalue' value='<?php echo $_POST['myvalue'];?>' />` or another value. You can use this to store values between page views provided the user submits the form.

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in `$_SESSION` but it's unreliable as they could simply keep resetting the session cookie. I would recommend you use [`memcache`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) or [`apc_store`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) depending which one you run and identify by IP address.

Comment: Can we consider values in DB as another option ?

Comment: We can, but you'll need to then setup a cron or scheduled event to decrease the counter after an expiry period (or keep them indefinitely), it's also not quite as efficient.

Comment: no cron required. just give them X minute slot SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bad_logins WHERE username='POSTED USERNAME' AND login_attept_date>DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERNAL X MINUTE)

Comment: @Waygood that falls into the "or keep them indefinitely" option

Comment: not if you do cleanups too before checks DELETE FROM bad_logins WHERE login_attampt_date<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)  so each login will also clean

Comment: And also `SELECT count(id) FROM bad_logins WHERE ip_addr=INET_ATON(:ip) AND date>DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL X MINUTE)` would be more appropriate as he doesn't have a username yet :)

Comment: @Waygood it's a bit hacky and could cause excessive QPS. In this scenario it's better to use a scheduled event, and better still to use a caching solution (redis, memcache, apc).

Comment: good idea @Martin you could do both AND then do an IP check for say 10 bad entries. That will then allow an office/school (multiple users) with one IP address or one with a bonded internet connection (random ip)

Comment: @Waygood Yep, you're right a combination of the two is a good idea to combat proxies or bot nets

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Session and save the logins to these session.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['logonCounter'])) {
    $_SESSION['LogonCounter'] = 0;
}

if($LogonFail == true) { // do something that check if its correct
    $_SESSION['LogonCounter']++;
}

if($_SESSION['LogonCounter'] < 3) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the counter in SESSION and increment its value at each failure login .. Otherwise you can create a table in database and keep the login attempts in a row along with user's ip address. With second way you can permanently block some ip's if you need ...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use a database so that you can see what is happening and it is not as easy to avoid by a hacker, but using just php you can store the number of login attempts in a session variable:

```
<?php
// only check on posts
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['login_attempts'] = isset($_SESSION['login_attempts']) ? ($_SESSION['login_attempts'] + 1) : 0;
  // do checking on number of attempts
  if ($_SESSION['login_attempts'] > 3)
  {
    echo "Go Away! Hacker!";
    die();
    // or just do a redirect to another page...
  }
}
?>
<center><form action="" method="post"><br>
...
```

Comment: so where is the part where it checks if the $_SESSION['login_attempts'] > 3? and how can I use the $_SESSION variable in echoing login attempt #?

Comment: @Hanzo Kimura I didn't add that at first but now it is there. Note that you can use that variable anywhere in your script but you need to place `session_start();` at the very top, before any output to the browser.

Comment: I don't think the $_SESSION['login_attempts'] is incrementing cause i tried echo $_SESSION['login_attempts'] and it always print 0 after I click submit. Can it work using XAMMP only?

Comment: @Hanzo Kimura Yes, it seems `$_SESSION['login_attempts']++` did not work, I have changed it with `($_SESSION['login_attempts'] + 1)` and now it does.

Comment: @Hanzo Kimura You're welcome! Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['attempts']))
{
    if ($_SESSION['attempts'] == 3){
        echo "Go away!";
    } else {
      $_SESSION['attempts']=$_SESSION['attempts']+1;
    }
}
else
{
  $_SESSION['attempts']=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be best served to do this via sessions for a simple implementation.  However the user can easily terminate their session by deleting the session cookie.  Really the most secure way would be to log all login requests by IP address to a database and then display security warning if you had X number of failed requests from given IP addresses withn Y amount of time.